# UI is not re-rendring even though the store state is changing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have this main component which is connected to the redux store via connect method.

I am also using logger middleware in order to check the store state as it progressively changes and from there i can see the store is updating successfully but the component it is connected is not re rendering.

Please help....

I have tried almost everything including using Object.assign({}), spread operation and also tried using the componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) but still the ui is not updating.

Here is the Main app.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './MainComponent'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import firebase from './fbConfig'
import usersReducer from './reducers/usersReducer'
import logger from 'redux-logger'


// const rootReducer = combineReducers({
//     firebase: firebaseReducer,
// });

const data = window.data;

delete window.data;

const store = createStore(usersReducer, data, applyMiddleware(logger(), thunk));

store.subscribe(() => {
    // console.log("Store State : " + JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
});

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

where data is

```
{"users":[{"key":1,"value":{"employeeID":1,"firstName":"Siddharth Kilam","mobileNumber":"+919987792049","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:15:05","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":1},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:05:39","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":8,"employeeID":1},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"2019-04-11T04:34:00.000Z","endTime":"2019-04-11T12:34:00.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Inactive"}},{"key":145,"value":{"employeeID":145,"firstName":"SidKilam2 Motorola","mobileNumber":"9599936991","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-03 12:20:16","lat":28.4455203,"lon":77.101336,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-02 23:01:27","lat":28.4747009,"lon":77.0989274,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"1999-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","endTime":"2000-01-01T18:29:59.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Offline"}}]};
```

Reducer file is

```
const GET_TASKS = 'get tasks'

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TASKS:

      // return state.usersList.map(emp => {
      //   return Object.assign({}, emp.value, {
      //     firstName : "Neeraj Kumar Bansal"
      //   })
      // });

      return { ...state,  tasks : action.tasks }

    default:

      return state;
    }
 }
```

Action File Is

```
import database from '../fbConfig'

 /**
* ACTION TYPES
*/
const GET_TASKS = 'get tasks'

/**
* ACTION CREATORS
*/
export const getTasks = (tasks) => ({type: GET_TASKS, tasks})

/**
* THUNKS
*/
export function getTasksThunk() {
 return dispatch => {
 const tasks = [];
 database.ref(`/tasks/145/2019-01-14`).once('value', snap => {

  // console.log("Called ......................");

  snap.forEach(data => {
  let task = data.val();
  tasks.push(task)
  })

  // console.log("Tasks Fetched" + tasks);

 })
 .then(() => dispatch(getTasks(tasks)))
 }
}
```

UI Component IS :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firebaseConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import MapView from './components/map/MapView'
import MapComponents from './components/map/MapComponents';
import TasksSidebar from './components/map/TasksSidebar';
import { getTasksThunk } from './thunks/getTasksThunk'

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    // console.log("Props From Main Component : " + JSON.stringify(this.props.users));

    const { users } = this.props;
    // const { tasks } = this.state;

    console.log("Users From Main Component : " + users);
    // console.log("Tasks From Main Component : " + tasks);

    return (
      <div>
        <MapComponents users={users} />
        <TasksSidebar />
        <MapView users={users}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// export default compose(
//   firebaseConnect((props) => {
//     return [
//       'Tasks'
//     ]
//   }),
//   connect(
//     (state) => ({
//       tasks: state.firebase.data.Tasks,
//       // profile: state.firebase.profile // load profile
//     })
//   )
// )(App)

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log("Map State to props : " + state);
  return {
    users : state.users,
    tasks : state.tasks
  }
}

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  dispatch(getTasksThunk())
  return {

  }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(App);
```

The UI should re render as the store state changes....

Answer (score 0):

Use static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle component. As it executes for each re-rendering.

You may check the condition there, if there are no changes just return null otherwise update the state there. In getDerived state from props, you may set the state by returning an object. the setState function won't work here, since it is a static method. kindly refer this link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

```
// alter your store and reducer file
const store = createStore(usersReducer, applyMiddleware(logger(), thunk));

const GET_TASKS = 'get tasks';
const initialState = {
   users: [{"key":1,"value":{"employeeID":1,"firstName":"Siddharth Kilam","mobileNumber":"+919987792049","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:15:05","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":1},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-09 09:05:39","lat":28.4453983,"lon":77.1012133,"eventTypeID":8,"employeeID":1},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"2019-04-11T04:34:00.000Z","endTime":"2019-04-11T12:34:00.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Inactive"}},{"key":145,"value":{"employeeID":145,"firstName":"SidKilam2 Motorola","mobileNumber":"9599936991","adminName":"Sid Kilam","adminID":36,"profileName":"default","profileID":4,"explicitLogin":1,"locRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-03 12:20:16","lat":28.4455203,"lon":77.101336,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"attendanceRow":{"timestamp":"2019-04-02 23:01:27","lat":28.4747009,"lon":77.0989274,"eventTypeID":9,"employeeID":145},"workingStatus":{"code":0,"reason":"Normal Day","shifts":[{"startTime":"1999-12-31T18:30:00.000Z","endTime":"2000-01-01T18:29:59.000Z"}]},"offlinePeriod":3600000,"status":"Offline"}}],
   tasks: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TASKS:
      return { ...state,  tasks : action.tasks }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firebaseConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import MapView from './components/map/MapView'
import MapComponents from './components/map/MapComponents';
import TasksSidebar from './components/map/TasksSidebar';
import { getTasksThunk } from './thunks/getTasksThunk'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){

     if(props.users !== state.users){
        return {
           users: props.users    // This will update the props value for users in state
        }
     }

     return null;
  }

  render() {

    // console.log("Props From Main Component : " + JSON.stringify(this.props.users));

    const { users } = this.state;
    // const { tasks } = this.state;

    console.log("Users From Main Component : " + users);
    // console.log("Tasks From Main Component : " + tasks);

    return (
      <div>
        <MapComponents users={users} />
        <TasksSidebar />
        <MapView users={users}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  //console.log("Map State to props : " + state);
  return {
    users : state.users,
    tasks : state.tasks
  }
}

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  dispatch(getTasksThunk())
  return {

  }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(App);
```

Comment: did you got the value from state.users ie this.props.users

Comment: No empty array.

Comment: I have updated the store and reducer file, Can you try like that, then it will get the value from this.props.users. And it will re-render the updated values

Comment: still not getting the value from this.props.users

Comment: `this.props.users` will not be there, if it isn't in your store. You might want to check `this.props.tasks`

Comment: but we are getting users from my initial state, and this.props.tasks is also not working

Comment: logger shows the exact data that i want to be: users : ... and tasks : ...

Comment: Is the `console.log("Map State to props : " + state);` working?